# The Medrash and Gemara about Hoshana Rabbah

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, midrash, rosh-hashanah-new-year, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

I read on [*shirat devorah*](http://shiratdevorah.blogspot.com/) the following:

1) The *Midrash* tells us that G‑d told Abraham: *“If atonement is not granted to your children on Rosh Hashanah, I will grant it on Yom Kippur; if they do not attain atonement on Yom Kippur, it will be given on Hoshana Rabbah.”*

Where does the Midrash say this?

2) Isaiah says, *“They seek Me day [after] day.”*

Where does Isaiah say this?

The Talmud explains that these two “days” refer to the day when the shofar is sounded [Rosh Hashanah] and the day when we take the willow [Hoshana Rabbah]—the day when the heavenly judgment begins, and the day when it concludes.

Where does the Gemara say this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isaiah [(58:2)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1058.htm):

> **וְאוֹתִי, יוֹם יוֹם יִדְרֹשׁוּן**, וְדַעַת דְּרָכַי, יֶחְפָּצוּן; כְּגוֹי אֲשֶׁר-צְדָקָה עָשָׂה, וּמִשְׁפַּט אֱלֹהָיו לֹא עָזָב, יִשְׁאָלוּנִי מִשְׁפְּטֵי-צֶדֶק, קִרְבַת אֱלֹהִים יֶחְפָּצוּן

The Yerushalmi Rosh Hashana (4:8) says:

> ואותי יום יום ידרושון זו תקיעה וערבה

The reference is to the Aravah ceremony which was performed on the day known as Hoshana Rabba. I see no reference in the Yerushalmi to Hoshana Rabba as a day of judgement.

The Paneach Razza makes a brief reference to the Midrash about Avraham and Hoshana Rabba in Parshas Emor:

> הושענה רבה וכמאמרם במדרש שאמר הקב"ה לאברהם אבינו וכו'

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah you are welcome. BTW simply googling " Isaiah says, “They seek Me day [after] day.” yields the verse, and other online tools make it fairly easy to find most Jewish sources if you know what you are looking for. One excellent source is the [Bar-Ilan online search database](http://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=advancedSearch!yes).