# Flying to Eretz Yisrael or G-d transporting him to there?

Tags: miracle, golus-exile, aliya-laaretz, messianic-redemption

We say three times a day, "Sound the great shofar for our freedom... and gather us together from the four corners of the earth."

Does "gather us together from the four corners of the earth" mean that Hashem, Himself, will transport us to Eretz Yisrael miraculously or does one need to go to an airport and board a plane?

Comment: Why would this be any different from any other blessing in the Amidah which asks for help in various areas, e.g. health, wealth, etc. but doesn't absolve a person of personal responsibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rambam writes ([Hilkhot Teshuva 9:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1509.htm)) that his predecessors (cf. Berakhot 34b)[i] write that there is no difference between this era, and the coming epoch, except foreign subjugation (which will be lifted):

> וכבר אמרו חכמים הראשונים, אין בין העולם הזה לימות המשיח אלא שיעבוד מלכייות בלבד.

Accordingly, there would be no mass miraculous transportation to Israel, and in order to get there you would have to take a plane, or some other natural form of transportation.

---

[i] And Shabbat 63a, 151b, Pesahim 68a, Sanhedrin 91b, and 99b.

Comment: Then why are we asking G-d to gather us if we have to make the effort in getting there?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah For the same reason that we ask him for wealth, even though we get jobs, and we ask him for health, even though we go to doctors.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah  Specifically one should realize that for much of the last two millennia, the idea of being able to live in Israel was the stuff of fantasy, even though they could transport themselves there, through natural means.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Consider marking an answer correct, here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64309/8775.

Comment: So why aren't Jews all over the world making aliyah?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah How is that question related to any of my comments?

Comment: If we asking G-d to gather us together from the four corners of the earth, then that should mean that Jews should be buying a one way ticket to Eretz Yisrael to live there permanently.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - Some are unable, either financially or other reasons, to make aliyah. That is what we are davening for. That every Jew will have the means and support to be able to make aliyah in the end of times.

Comment: [(http://bit.ly/2fAZPsq) Top 10 Reasons Jews DON'T Make Aliyah]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as many disagree with the Rambam about this and we don't know who will be correct and whether or not there will be miracles.

Comment: @Jay Inasmuch as it is a question about Judaism, rather than a question about the future, answers based on authoritative Jewish sources, are acceptable. In this case, that source is the opinion cited in the Talmud Berakhot, Shabbat, Pesahim, Sanhedrin, and in turn by Rambam. || It is indeed true that others disagree, (although they wouldn't necessarily disagree regarding the case at hand).

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah If you want to ask why some people don't make aliyah, a) its completely unrelated to this answer. b) [It has already been asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/what-justifications-are-there-for-not-moving-to-eretz-yisrael). c) The article you linked to is basically a string of unfounded accusations, that adds nothing in the way of meaningful content, and is rather offensive.